# What is the difference between `which <command>` and `command -v <command>`?

Tags: which

When I put in `which npm`, I get `/usr/local/bin/npm`. When I put in `command -v npm`, I get `/usr/bin/npm`.

Why is that? What's the difference? `man which` says `which` "returns the pathnames of the filenames that would be executed in the current environment". I see that if I run `which -a npm`, it returns both of the paths mentioned above.

So why does it pick the first one when run without `-a`, while `command -v npm` returns the second one?

Comment: Does this (or the duplicate) answer your question? [why does shell use executable in /usr/bin and not in /usr/local/bin](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/554785).  Also: [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249)

Answer (score 2):

`which` is an external command from the `csh` times that is not related to Bourne compatible shells.

As a result, it may return wrong results unless you use `csh`.

So better use built in shell commands...

`command` is a built in command from POSIX compatible shells and together with the other builtin `type` returns the right results for shells that are similar to the Bourne Shell.